# VFL that makes two buttons aligns to two edges

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to make two buttons that aligns to left edge and right edge, but following VFL failed.

`@"H:|[leftToolbar(60)]-[rightToolbar(60)]|"`

The result looks like they all pushed to the left, the second right toolbar was not pushed to the right.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@"H:|[leftToolbar(60)]-[rightToolbar(60)]|"` says this ...

- leftToolbar width should be `(60)`
- rightToolbar width should be `(60)`
- space between leftToolbar right edge and rightToolbar left edge should be standard (20, 8, ... depends on situation) (`...]-[...`)
- leftToobar left edge should be aligned with superviews left edge (`|[...`)
- rightToolbar right edge should be aligned with superviews right edge (`...]|`)

If standard space is 20 for example and your superview width is not `60+20+60=140` I would expect *random* results.

You can split it in two VFLs ...

- `@"H:|[leftToolbar(60)]"`
- `@"H:[rightToolbar(60)]|"`

... which says 60 for both buttons, one aligned to the left, another aligned to the right and I don't care whats between them and even if they overlap or not in case of small views.

Or do what Praveen recommends, but play with priorities (`@...`) to say what's more important for you. For example item width, or spacing between them, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this @"H:|[leftToolbar(==rightToolbar)]-[rightToolbar(==60)]|"